# Which solution has better performance when counting with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities.One is Product and the Other is ProductCategory.Product to ProductCategory relationship is Many to one.I have a method to get all ProductCategories.I want to add a transient variable productCount to ProductCategory where it shous how many products are available for each ProductCategory.I have 2 solutions for these.Both are working fine.

solution 1

```
public List<ProductCategory> getProductCategoryList() {

List<ProductCategory> productCategoryList = this
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT pc FROM ProductCategory pc")
            .list();

    for (ProductCategory category : productCategoryList) {
        String categoryId = category.getId().toString();
        category.setProductsCount(getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE  p.productCategory.id=:categoryId")
                .setParameter("categoryId", Long.parseLong(categoryId))
                .list().size());
    }
return productCategoryList;
}
```

solution 2

```
public List<ProductCategory> getProductCategoryList() {

List<ProductCategory> productCategoryList = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();
    List<Object[]> resultList = this.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("FROM Product p  right join  p.productCategory")
            .list();

    for (Object[] array : resultList) {
        Product product = null;
        ProductCategory productCategory = null;

        if (array[1] != null) {
            productCategory = (ProductCategory) array[1];
        }
        if (array[0] != null) {
            product = (Product) array[0];
            productCategory.setProductsCount(productCategory
                    .getProductsCount() == null ? 1 : productCategory
                    .getProductsCount() + 1);

        }
        if (productCategory != null
                && !productCategoryList.contains(productCategory)) {

            productCategoryList.add(productCategory);

        }

    }

    return productCategoryList;
}
```

What is the better solution from these two? Or any other better solution ? 
I don't have a sound knowledge on comparison of performances in hibernate.

Comment: Write a test application and measure the time the two implementations are running.

Comment: My guess is that the second will be quicker as it makes a single database call... what size is the result list likely to be?

Comment: Best would be to use solution one with a SELECT COUNT(p) instead of making a list and counting the elements.

Comment: Why are you fetching all the products if you are just interested in count. Why not use a count query? Generally a product category should have many products, thus fetching all of them into memory doesn't make much sense. Use the first approach and just fetch the count.

Comment: @user714965 Thanks for the comment and it is true But I want to get some ideas on what is better way to achieve the results in technical aspect.And also to find a best.Not just the time wise performance measurement

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra result list is no more than 20

Comment: @Theolodis there are many db queries in solution1 ,solution 2 its 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these solutions are complex, and load all the products of the categories from the database. If you're ready to do that, why don't you simply make the association bidirectional, and simply call `category.getProducts().size()` to get your count?

If you really don't want to do that, then you should simply execute a query to get the categories, and then execute a single additional query to get their product count from the database:

```
select category.id, count(product.id) from Product product
inner join product.category category
where category.id in :categoryIds
group by category.id
```

This will return a `List<Object[]>`, where each `Object[]` contains one of the category IDs, and the associated count of products.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always going to get this "property" then I think you could use `@Formula` at you POJO and let this be more transparent.

Something like this on `ProductCategory.java` (needs testing):

```
@Formula("(select count(*) from Product p where p.productCategory.id = id)")
private Long productsCount;
```

Where id is the id field on `ProductCategory.java`.

**EDIT**
By the way, don't worry about performance now. Just make the code clear.. Once you have it running and working, you may profile the system and see where it needs tunning.